# Show rows with highest number, even if it's the same

Tags: php, sql

I'm using the following SQL

```sql
SELECT 
    testjob.id AS id,
    testjob.EndTime AS Date,
    testsuitecollectionname,
    testsuitecollection,
    TestSuiteName,
    TestSuite
FROM
    Testreportingdebug.testjob
        LEFT JOIN
    testsuitecollection ON testsuitecollection.id = testjob.testsuitecollectionid
        LEFT JOIN
    testsuitecollectionlink ON testsuitecollection.id = testsuitecollectionlink.testsuitecollection
        LEFT JOIN
    testsuite ON testsuite.id = testsuitecollectionlink.testsuite
WHERE
    testjob.Engine = 'SeqZap'
        AND TestSuiteName IN (
        'AlertManagement')
        AND testjob.EndTime IN ('2020-05-18 05:18:58','7305', '2020-03-18 04:57:31', 'gin_mixit_simulated', '34', 'AlertManagement', '987'
, '2020-05-17 16:39:03', '2020-03-03 18:07:28', '2020-05-18 16:07:44')
        AND testjob.id IN ('13382', '13372', '5921', '13391', '7305')
ORDER BY TestSuiteName;
```

and I get the following
[Rows from table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDn7H.png)

Is it possible to filter this table so I get only the rows marked here:
[Wanted rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH725.png)

NOTE: I can have multiple *TestSuiteNames*, and they have to always with the highest date, and show all rows for it.

Could it be possible to use MAX(testjob.EndTime), and then if there is more than one Max date for that specific *TestSuiteName*, then it shows them, instead not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    testjob.id AS id,
    testjob.EndTime AS Date,
    testsuitecollectionname,
    testsuitecollection,
    TestSuiteName,
    TestSuite
FROM
    Testreportingdebug.testjob
        LEFT JOIN
    testsuitecollection ON testsuitecollection.id = testjob.testsuitecollectionid
        LEFT JOIN
    testsuitecollectionlink ON testsuitecollection.id = testsuitecollectionlink.testsuitecollection
        LEFT JOIN
    testsuite ON testsuite.id = testsuitecollectionlink.testsuite
WHERE
    testjob.Engine = 'SeqZap'
        AND TestSuiteName IN (
        'AlertManagement')
        AND testjob.EndTime IN ('2020-05-18 05:18:58','7305', '2020-03-18 04:57:31', 'gin_mixit_simulated', '34', 'AlertManagement', '987'
, '2020-05-17 16:39:03', '2020-03-03 18:07:28', '2020-05-18 16:07:44')
        AND testjob.id IN ('13382', '13372', '5921', '13391', '7305')
        AND testsuitecollectionname = 'ceops1_pwm64_circ1'
ORDER BY TestSuiteName;
```

How about that?

Added (one line above Order by):
`AND testsuitecollectionname = 'ceops1_pwm64_circ1'`

Comment: Changed my question a bit